# setTextAppearance() doesn't work on Android

Tags: java, android

I've tried set style of text  programmatically in `RadioButton`, but they set only size and color. But if I set style through XML it works fine. I tried set style in `TextView` same situation. What am I doing wrong?

Java code:

```
public class YourProgOneApps extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

RadioGroup radioGender, radioTarget, radioWhere;
RadioButton man, woman, build_muscle, fat_loss, keep_in_good_shape, gym, home;
TextView textView2;
Button btnExeProgOne;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_prog1);

    radioGender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGender);
    man = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.man);
    woman = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.woman);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView2.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.radio_chek_f_pre_f); 
    man.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.radio_chek_f_pre_f);
    radioTarget = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioTarget);
    radioWhere = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioWhere);
  }
public void onClick(View v) {}
}
```

style.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
<style name="radio_chek_f_pre_f">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/radio_right</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>   
    <item name="android:textColor">#b4b4b4</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I noticed in the documentation that TextAppearance is sort of missing the method are yo using. Could you please reference the version of Android you are using?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAppearance

Comment: 2.3.3. on Eclipse. But here nothing is said about the deprecation method [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)

Comment: Same problem in 2020...

Comment: (Note: what actually isn't working in my case is to set the theme, which includes attributes like `colorControlNormal`. Normal text styling, like text color works)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling invalidate() if you are on a UI thread or postInvalidate() if you are not on a UI thread.

In your example you seem to be on the UI thread so try calling Invalidate on that textview.

This should force it to redraw, and although I imagine setTextAppearance would do this automatically, its worth a shot.